Can't use xvfb-run twice while building Docker image
I've been stuck with this problem for a few days already. No solutions found even after a lot of research.
Basically, I'm trying to build a docker image and need to install (among other things) Visual Studio and Python using wine. For both I'm required to run the installer using xvfb-run command.
Below is my input code (snippet from my Dockerfile):
RUN apt install xvfb winetricks -y
RUN xvfb-run -a winetricks -q vcrun2015
RUN sleep 30

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.9/python-3.11.9-amd64.exe
RUN xvfb-run -a wine python-3.11.9-amd64.exe /quiet TargetDir=C:\\Python\\Python311 Include_doc=0 InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1
RUN sleep 30

First xvfb-run command runs successfully (-a parameter takes server :99 as default) and installs vcrun2015 successfully.
Second xvfb-run takes another server (:100) but returns the following error:
RUN xvfb-run -a wine python-3.11.9-amd64.exe /quiet TargetDir=C:\Python\Python311 Include_doc=0 InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1:
3.848 X connection to :100 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
3.848 X connection to :100 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

Both installations work individually. The issue is really in the second xvfb-run execution.
What I've tried so far:

Different versions of Wine and Ubuntu.
Pass --server-num manually instead of using -a. Whatever server number I pass in second xvfb-run execution, it will be referenced in the error message.
Instantiate each Xvfb as background process (Xvfb :99 -ac &) but unable to kill them in Dockerfile; also tried using tini.
Run the two xvfb-run commands from a .sh file using RUN command in Dockerfile.


What's your goal with this setup?  Can you use a Windows VM, or the standard Docker Hub python image, without going through these steps?  Using WINE to try to run a Windows application in a semi-isolated Linux container seems like a roundabout approach.

Thanks David. Using python on Windows is a requirement, as one of the libraries I need only work in Windows' python installation.

It seems like your container environment is using the wrong operating system, then.  Can you use a Windows-native container, maybe using an image like python:3.12-windowsservercore?

My Docker installation doesn't allow me to switch to Windows containers, likely because my Windows is Home Edition. Docker docs mention that it will only work on Windows 10 and 11 Professional and Enterprise.
